# Get selected Dropdown list (Thymeleaf)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I created a user with some information including Roles, I went to get a pre-selected user Roles dropdown list for modification. Now I can modify it but cannot get the list of Roles for this user, in the view a have all roles stored in database.

Someone con help me how to resolve it
 this is my thymeleaf code to get the list of roles :

```xml
<select id="role" name="role" class="user-form-control"
        multiple="multiple">
    <option th:each="role : ${roles}" th:value="${role.name}"
            th:attr="choiceid=${role.name}" th:text="${role.name}">
    </option>
</select>
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/edit/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public RedirectView modifyUser(@PathVariable String userId, @ModelAttribute(value = "user") UserDto userto,
            Model model) {

        Integer valueUserId;
        try {
            valueUserId = Integer.parseInt(userId);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return new RedirectView("/error");
        }
        UserDto user = userProvider.getUserById(valueUserId);
        String pass = user.getPassword();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userto, user);
        user.setIdUser(valueUserId);
        user.setPassword(pass);

        return userProvider.modifyUser(user) ? new RedirectView("/users") : new RedirectView("/error");
    }
```

My Role controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/roles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getRoles(Model modelUser){

        UserDto user = userService.getLoggedUser();
        List<String> userRoles = user.getRole(); 
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("role/roles");
        }
        modelUser.addAttribute("userRoles", userRoles);

        List<RoleDto> roles =roleProvider.getRoles();   
        model.addObject("roles",roles);
        model.addObject("userRoles", userRoles);
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/roles/edit/{roleId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getRole(@PathVariable String roleId){
        Integer valueRoleId;
        try{
            valueRoleId = Integer.parseInt(roleId);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }

        RoleDto role = roleProvider.getRoleById(valueRoleId);
        ModelAndView model;

        if (role == null){
            model = new ModelAndView("error");
        }
        else{
            model = new ModelAndView("role/rolemodify");
            model.addObject("role",role);
            model.addObject("path","/roles/edit/"+role.getIdRole());
        }
        return model;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your controller? It would help to see how you're passing the roles to the thyme leaf template

Comment: i shared it, thank you

Comment: It doesn't look as though you're adding your roles to the model. You'll have to create List<Role> and then add it as it to your model with the name `"roles"`. it should look something like `model.addAttribute("roles", roleList)`

Comment: i created a list : List<String> roles = user.getRole(); and i added it to the model : model.addAttribute("roles", roles); i got the same result

Comment: You need to create a `Role` class and give it a `name` field.  When thymeleaf looks for `role.name` it's actually looking for a `getName()` method in the `Role` class

Comment: con you check my Role controller please

Answer (score 0):

Your role controller looks fine. You could edit your modifyUser method like so to add your roles to the template:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/edit/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public RedirectView modifyUser(@PathVariable String userId, @ModelAttribute(value = "user") UserDto userto,
        Model model) {

    Integer valueUserId;
    try {
        valueUserId = Integer.parseInt(userId);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return new RedirectView("/error");
    }
    //new code
    List<RoleDto> roles = roleProvider.getRoles(); //maybe print these in a loop to verify it's getting the roles correctly from the database. 
    model.addAttributes("roles", roles); 

    UserDto user = userProvider.getUserById(valueUserId);
    String pass = user.getPassword();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(userto, user);
    user.setIdUser(valueUserId);
    user.setPassword(pass);

    return userProvider.modifyUser(user) ? new RedirectView("/users") : new RedirectView("/error");
}
```

You'll have to `@Autowire` your `roleProvider` into your user controller.

Make sure your `RoleDto` class has a name field and the getter is `getName()`. Naming conventions are important in spring.

Comment: allways i got all list of roles without pre-selected Roles. i don't know if i need to change something in the thymeleaf code.

Comment: @Ing_ULT I'm not sure what you mean?